# Displaying overlay in camera intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, camera

The user can open the default camera by clicking a button using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent.

Is there a way to display an overlay while using the default camera?
For example a rectangular box with text in it, in the bottom right corner of the screen, so the user knows what part of the picture is supposed to be in this position.

Here is my Camera Intent:

```
fun cameraIntent(context: Context): Intent {
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_"
    val storageDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val filephoto = File.createTempFile(
        imageFileName, /* prefix */
        ".jpg", /* suffix */
        storageDir      /* directory */
    )
    imageURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.nlp_expense_tracker.fileprovider", filephoto)
    val pictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageURI)
    return pictureIntent
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to display an overlay while using the default camera?

Not really. Beyond the base technical challenges, there are hundreds of camera apps that the user might wind up using. You have no good way of knowing if your overlay conflicts with how that camera app is set up (e.g., your box blocks the ability for the user to take the picture).

> For example a rectangular box with text in it, in the bottom right corner of the screen, so the user knows what part of the picture is supposed to be in this position.

Perhaps you should be using CameraX or [another camera library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/141?sort=created) and taking the pictures directly in your app. Then, you have far greater control over the user interface, including showing messages like the one that you propose.

Comment: Yeah i was afraid that this was going to be the answer, since using camerax seems more complicated if i also want to use the ML-Kit text recognition, but i guess thats what I'll have to do, Thanks!

Comment: @dkiwikid: "using camerax seems more complicated if i also want to use the ML-Kit text recognition" -- if anything, I would expect it to be easier in the long run. Please understand that those hundreds of camera apps are very buggy. So, for example, you might not get the photo saved in the location that you requested in `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: Since i already built the app and its working I'm always scared to change stuff, since I'm also very new to programming, but I guess I will have to do it with camera x. 
But do I understand it correctly that the view you get using camerax is always on the activity or fragment you call the camerax API? 
So I would have to create a new fragment (Or is an Acitivity better for the purpose of the camera?) that opens when i click the button "Take picture"?

Comment: @dkiwikid: " So I would have to create a new fragment... that opens when i click the button "Take picture"?" -- yes, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. I done this about a year ago. I used this repository as my guide.

https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo

If you look classes inside this repo , you will get the idea. I couldn't find my own code yet. But this not so easy. I think using CameraX could be more easy solution.